# Write console output to file

Tags: c#, console, output

Really new to this, I've read the answers on here and they have helped so far but I am still a bit stuck.

I have managed to create a program that displays the users starsign from DOB input.

Now I want to send the results to a text file. I can create the file but I do not know how to send the console output/result of the program to the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-application?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420429/mirroring-console-output-to-a-file?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create);
// First, save the standard output.
TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.WriteLine("Hello file");
Console.SetOut(tmp);
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
sw.Close();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx

Comment: Technically correct but doubling up every write operation will get quite unwieldy quickly.  A more manageable approach would be to either build up a a large string for output at the end & then write it out twice or write a class that multiplexes output to multiple streams.

Answer (score 1):

If you have calculated the date of birth and written it to the console, you have the answer stored in a variable, then all you need to do is write that out to the text file - unless I am missing some in the problem?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: +1: This is likely correct approach to the problem itself, also not immediate answer to OP's question.